# how do variable substitution in socket.send function

Tags: java, karate

When I am trying to send some values to socket.send() method it does does do variable substitution? for e.g.
* def payload = {a:'1', b:'2'}
* socket.send('#(payload)')

I have tried  * socket.send('#(strpayload)')

```
Given request signIn
    * def token = signIn.token.token
    Given def demoBaseUrl = 'wss://someapi:someport/'
    And def socket = karate.webSocket(demoBaseUrl)
    And def authpayload = {type:"auth", payload:{token:'#(token)'}}
    * socket.send('#(authpayload)')
```

I am expecting that once before sending the value to socket variable should substituted however if send the values as it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that the `'#(foo)'` placeholder style only works on the Right Hand Side of a `match` or `def` or when you `read()` a `*.json` file.

Here it is simple, just use plain JS:

```
* socket.send(authpayload)
```